# Specify controller outside of namespace in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have this current setup that worked:

```
concern :commentable do
  resources :comments, only: %i[create destroy], controller: '/comments'
end
```

and it used under routes as

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :discussions, concerns: %i[commentable]
end
```

In rails 6 when I do this I get:

> ArgumentError ('/comments' is not a supported controller name. This can lead to potential routing problems. See https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-a-controller-to-use):

How do I specify a controller that is outside of the current module of the route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I didn't found a fix for this but I found a workaround.

Replace `namespace :admin` with `scope '/admin/', module: :admin, as: :admin` then you can use `controller: '/comments'` to refer controllers outside of the current namespace.

```
concern :commentable do
  resources :comments, only: %i[create destroy], controller: '/comments'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is here:

```rb
concern :commentable do
  resources :comments, only: %i[create destroy], controller: :comments # No '/comments'
end
```

This will automatically serve `POST /comments` and `DELETE /comments/:id`. Then when you mount this concern on your namespace should work fine

Comment: Doesn't work when included under the namespace declaration. It is looking for controller `admin/comments` so this is the current problem.